# How can I avoid deadlocks with my queue table on MariaDB/Galera?

Tags: mysql, deadlock, mariadb, galera

I have a database table that is basically a first-in-first-out queue. Rows are simply inserted into the table by other parts of the system and forgotten about. Every 5 minutes, a job runs to process items from the queue. Each row to be processed has it's status field changed from a pending value to a processing value. Subsequent duplicates in the queue are matched up and marked as the duplicate of an earlier queued item that is being processed. The queue processor job is the only thing that does anything with the table, apart from the parts of the system which just blindly insert rows.

This is exactly what the processor does with the queue:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id
FROM api_queue
WHERE status=:status_processing

-- Application checks this result set is empty, then...

UPDATE api_queue qs
INNER JOIN api_queue qdupes ON qdupes.products_id=qs.products_id AND qdupes.action=qs.action
SET qdupes.status = IF(qs.id=qdupes.id, :status_processing, :status_processing_duplicate)
WHERE qs.id IN (:queue_ids) ;

COMMIT;

-- Each queue item is processed

-- Once processing is complete, we purge the queue

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM api_queue WHERE status = :status_processing ;

-- Application sanity checks the number of processing items it's about to delete against how many it's processed, and then...

DELETE FROM api_queue WHERE status IN (:status_processing, :status_processing_duplicate) ;

COMMIT;
```

In a typical 5 minutes, the queue will build up a backlog of about 100 items, though occasionally it can be in the thousands if a lot of changes have occurred in the catalog.

The first transaction is typically pretty fast when it doesn't hit a deadlock (0.1 - 0.2 seconds to complete), but it does seem to hit deadlocks about 10% of the time.

Why does it hit deadlocks so often? Even if a transaction locks all the rows currently in a table, should I expect this to cause contention when new rows are added to the table? If so, why is that?

I've also noticed that sometimes the first transaction above (containing the `UPDATE` query) doesn't appear to actually apply at all - though I think this may well be an unrelated bug.

My queue table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api_queue` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `action` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `triggered_by` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

My Mantra:  "Don't queue it, just do it".  I say this because I have seen too many queues implemented in MySQL that flopped for one reason or another.  A common reason is that the overhead of inserting/checking/removing the items may be as costly as "just doing the task".  So why double the cost?  And, apparently, the queuing is causing extra deadlocks.

According to the info you gave, the system should be able to handle 1500-3000 every 5 minutes.  That should handle the "100" to "thousands".

Your queuing mechanism seems overly complex since it involves a `JOIN` and other things that are not simply 1-in, 1-out.

Assuming you reject my comments so far, I will proceed to critique the code...

```
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
```

is possibly required for the both `SELECTs`.

The `SELECT` next to the `DELETE` could possibly be merged with the `DELETE` as a multi-table `DELETE`.  Or it might be possible to pull it, plus the associated code, out of the transaction.  (Faster transactions are less likely to deadlock.)

You are checking for errors (deadlock, etc) after the `COMMITs`, yes?  That's when Galera gets the hit.

When using an `IN(...)`, sort the elements.  The underlying code is probably locking the rows in the order of the `IN` elements.  This *could* turn a deadlock into a delay of up to `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` seconds.  (Such a delay is not as 'bad' as a deadlock.)

You repeat the transaction when it gets a deadlock, correct?  (That's the simple way to deal with deadlocks.)

**Edit (IN)**

If one thread is doing `UPDATE ... WHERE id IN (11,22)` and another is doing `UPDATE ... WHERE id IN (22,11)`, and each gets one row locked, then trying to get the other row locked is a deadlock -- and one would have to `ROLLBACK`.  If, instead, both said (11,22), then (at worst) one would have to wait (but not be deadlocked).  I am assuming, without proof, that InnoDB code is not cleaver enough to somehow avoid this `IN` deadlock -- by sorting the number, by atomically locking, or whatever.  (And I would argue that cleaver=slower, hence not worth doing for such a rare happening.)

Comment: The job it's queuing typically takes 3-5 minutes to complete whether it's for 1 item or a batch of 1000. The API task it performs is also throttled at 1 request per minute. I'm not "rejecting" your comments, but in this case it seems queuing and grouping the items is the only option.

Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, I check for deadlocks on _all_ queries (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `COMMIT`, etc). Yes I retry in the event of a deadlock. I still don't understand why my code would cause them. Could you further explain the `IN` ordering suggestion?

Comment: Ahh, of course. I'll try it, but I'm still not convinced that this will be the cause of the deadlocks in this case though, as only the one process will ever be modifying the rows. I've taken your advice and simplified the queue though, using the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` described [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/38823) to avoid duplicates. I didn't want to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because that would potentially cause further deadlocks (that's why I chose to do it the way I was doing it before). This new way seems better (and less complex).